# Make it possible to retract flags on comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

I have noticed that if I mistakenly flag a comment, I am not able to retract the flag afterwards. I think it would be a good feature to add the possibility to retract flags on comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) request on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/270345).